# RegEx for excluding repeating single characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that matches a repeating pattern or two or more characters (excluding a single repeating character) three or more times.

`(.)\1{3,}` will match a single repeated character e.g. matches `aaaa` but not `ababab` or `abcde`

`(.+)\1{3,}` will match a repeated patern e.g. `aaa`, `ababab`, `ab ab ab` but not `abcde`

I want to match only `ababab`, `ab ab ab`  etc
but not `aaaa` or `abcde`

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Would `aabaabaab` be considered a match?

Comment: Are you matching against the whole input string? or they may exist within a larger text?

Comment: The match may exist within a larger text

Comment: `aabaabaab` would be a match because the string `aab` is repeating

Comment: If it may exist within a larger text, does it happen within a single line or between other words? Because all the answers below assume that it happens in a separate line not between other texts.

Comment: What tool are you using this regex in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^((.)\2*?(?!\2).+?)\1{2,}$
```

The first part `((.)\2*?(?!\2).+?)` matches a string that has at least 2 different characters in it, then it repeats it at least 2 more times `\1{2,}`.

Breaking the first part down, we first match the first character, put it in group 2. Then we allow this character to repeat a few times, or not (`\2*`). Then we assert that there must be something else other than this character `(?!\2)`. And then we lazily match the rest `.+?`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u1VY7Q/2)

Comment: This works thank you. It needs to match to match a string in a larger text so I cant just remove the ^ and $

Comment: Removing the anchors should work in a larger text, but it is quite time consuming. I am not sure if it is at all possible to make this significantly quicker. As a workaround, what about splitting the larger text by some delimiter then check each split against the regex? @ToeNail

Answer (score 2):

As you want to discard matching if all the characters are same, you can use negative lookahead for rejecting that. In otherwise case, you can change `+` to `{2,}` in the quantifier where you are capturing the first part and then use `{2,}` so your matched first part repeats three or more times. You can use this regex,

```
^(?!(.)\1+$)(.{2,})\2{2,}$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?!(.)\1+$)` - This negative look ahead ensures if the string consists of only one character till end of string, then it rejects the match.
- `(.{2,})` - Match two or more any character and capture it in group2
- `\2{2,}` - Repeat what was captured in group2 two or more times
- `$` - End of string

[Regex Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/TItiG2/1)

Also, from your post, as you said you don't want to match `aaaa` since it has `aa` pattern repeated only two times and not three or more times, so if I am correct and you consider `aaaaaa` as a successful match, because now it has `aa` repeating three times, in that case you can get rid of negative lookahead from my above regex and use this regex which will not match `aaaa` but will match `aaaaaa` like I explained above.

```
^(.{2,})\1{2,}$
```

[Regex Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/TItiG2/2/)

Let me know if this is indeed what you wanted. In case of any queries, feel free to drop your comment.

Comment: This also works, thank you! Sorry if I wasnt clear in the statement but I do not want to match `aaaaaa` because it contains only a single character.

Comment: @ToeNail: Then my first assumption about your post and my first solution was correct. BTW, I answered your post the first and correctly with a simpler solution.

Comment: Sorry I read the solution from @Sweeper first as it was on top and did see your post as it was lower. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ToeNail: No issues :) and happy to help. Although apart from my answer being posted first, it is also more readable and maintainable. But it is up to you to select the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could check the length of what you're matching:

```
(.{2,})\1{3,}
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/V34YoD/1)

#### Regulex graph

[image]

Comment: Your regex matches `aaaaaaaa`

Comment: @revo Yes, it is correct because it maches three times `aa`. He didn't exclude it.

Comment: Sorry if the statement was clear but I wanted to exclude string that contained only a single character @Sweeper above has answered it clearly